# Django not serving static on digital ocean ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, nginx, server, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

**Run a collect static again and it worked!!!**

Tutorial for deployment followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#checking-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file

I have just successfully uploaded and run my project on digital ocean. It has been developed before production according to the coreyMS tutorials on youtube with the latest version of django 2.1.7. It has been deployed with this tutorial on ubuntu 18.04 on a digital ocean droplet.

I cant make it serve any static files.

The structure of my project is: newsite/myforum/ in here is the manage.py
In the newsite/myforum/myforum/ is the settings.py
and i have 3 apps users, forum and store that are all in folders in the newsite/myforum directory.

The static folder according to the coreyms tutorial for the latest django version is supposed to be in my main app, therefore forum/static/forum.
So the total path is newsite/myforum/forum/static/forum

My settings are:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In the nginx configuration i have specified the path, home/myuser/mydir/myenv/newsite/myforum
maybe i should try: home/myuser/mydir/myenv/newsite/myforum/forum/static/forum
or just: home/myuser/mydir/myenv/newsite/myforum/forum/static/

Or should i change my django settings and then run a collectstatic command.

It took me a long time to get this far with the deployment and i dont want to run a stupid command and ruin it.

Thank a lot for the help!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: have you run collectstatic yet?

Comment: Yes, i did it once when i first tested the app and it all worked fine like it did in this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#checking-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file but then i reach the end and no static appears anywhere. Do you think i should run it again now?

Comment: No, if you ran it on the server and it was showing the static files there is no reason for them to have disappeared.  Take a look at the html of the presented page and look to see where it is trying to download the static files from.  Is it giving 404 errors for them?

Comment: OMG, did another collectstatic and it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you HenryM!